# Android resource values folder

Tags: android, android-resources, genymotion, android-screen-support

How to create a resource values in Android application to match these **specific configurations**?
[image]

I'm debugging on Genymotion, with these configurations:
[image]

Already tried normal-notlong, but it doesn't match.
The device **has** virtual keyboard.

Thanks!

Comment: What are you expecting, In which folder it falls right? 160 dpi it falls into mdpi. Where you're facing issue

Comment: I want a folder (values-*) to match those configurations. It doesn't fall in "values-mdpi".

Comment: I have tried with you're configuration and it is picking for me correctly and I have checked out with same image with additonal text like (h, m , xh on it) and printed the metrics in log too. You try priniting log of screen pizxels and density and post it

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/P9dGz.png

Answer (score -1):

It it good if u download new device as per your criteria.

Changing on setting doesn't work.

Comment: My question was "How to create a resource values in Android application to match these specific configurations?". And yes, it does work.